# What is the Java code to subclass HtmlUnitDriver to support http authentication?

Tags: selenium2, java

Is it possible to subclass a Java object in the constructor?

I am a Java newbie trying out Selenium example in a faq, http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_How_do_I_handle_authentication_with_the_? where there is a note about how to modify an HtmlUnitDriver driver object to support authentication with some demo code I have repeated here.

After some asking in a stackoverflow thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605308/is-it-possible-to-subclass-a-java-object-in-the-constructor and learning more about Java, anonymous classes and overrides this is my current code, but I am getting a syntax error on the DefaultCredentialsProvider in Netbeans, and I am not sure whether it is due to the absence of required classes, or whether some more changes are required.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package seleniumtest01;

/**
 *
 * @author richard
 */
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCredentialsProvider;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
//import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.ChromeDriver;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
    // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface,
    // not the implementation.
    testBasicAuth();
    System.exit(0);
  }

  public static void testBasicAuth() {
    // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
    // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface,
    // not the implementation.
    //WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver() {

      @Override
      protected WebClient modifyWebClient(WebClient client) {
        // This class ships with HtmlUnit itself
        DefaultCredentialsProvider creds = DefaultCredentialsProvider();

        // Set some example credentials
        creds.addCredentials("username", "password");

        // And now add the provider to the webClient instance
        client.setCredentialsProvider(creds);

        return client;
      }
    };
    driver.get("http://user:selenium@192.168.1.2/");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Connection']"));
    element.click();
    //element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Admin Login']"));
    element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'admin/connection')]"));//[contains(@href,'#id1')]
    element.click();
    element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Connection 1']"));
    element.click();
    element = driver.findElement(By.name("field_one"));
    element.clear();
    element.sendKeys("sample text");
    //driver.findElement(By. id("submit")).click();
    element.submit();

    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    driver.quit();
  }


}
```

Bear with me, I learning Java via Selenium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
DefaultCredentialsProvider creds = DefaultCredentialsProvider();
```

to this:

```
DefaultCredentialsProvider creds = new DefaultCredentialsProvider();
```

Comment: nice hack, I will try it next time when creating new instance  ;)

Comment: @yoossiba, it's not a hack, it's proper syntax to construct objects in Java.